# SignalR Self Hosted Server 500 Error

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have recently taken an interest in SignalR but have yet to produce a working server, no matter how simple.

I have followed the GitHub Self Host [documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host) but I receive a nasty 500 Error.

The code I use is the following (basically the GitHub code):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string host = "http://localhost:2804";
        
        using (WebApplication.Start<InitialConf>(host))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server started on {0}", host);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

class InitialConf
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableCrossDomain = true
        };

        // Map to default /signalr route
        appBuilder.MapHubs(config);
    }
}

class fooHub : Hub
{
    public void DisplayTimeOnServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Browsing to `http://localhost:2804/signalr` produces a 500 Error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

I receive no exception / error in the application so I'm not sure why it behaves like this.

Anyone have any experiences with these issues? Or perhaps could lead me on to a better documentation on the matter?

Thank you

Comment: you can't browse to that but you can browse to http://localhost:2804/signalr/negotiate

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your Hub Class is private.
Just change that to  public.

```
public class fooHub : Hub
{
    public void DisplayTimeOnServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah the classic should-be-public-though-it-is-used-reflection. God damn it! I was so close to going insane!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to debug on the server?

And you are missing a function/definition in you Hub to inform your clients:

```
Clients.All.addMessage(message);
```

Other that that I suggest that you check the following resources:

Home page of SignalR - tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Scott's intro: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is any issue with setting up a route for your connection. After your application is running you should be able to go to /signalr/hubs and see the details about the hubs.